# Regex in MySQL: How to match every occurrence of a key against a value pattern?

Tags: mysql, regex, database, mysql-workbench, regex-group

I have these data:

What I need to do:
1) For every occurrence of `My-Name` dictionary key (which can occur 0 or more times), check that it is followed by a variable assignement AND has both words `Good` and `firstOnly` in any order, in that key value.

Examples of the data fields:

`Example#1` (should NOT match because `'My-Name'` does not contain both `Good` and `firstOnly`):

> {'Accept-Encoding, Accept', 'My-Name': 'PHPSESSID=bbb; path=/',
>   'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=14400'}

Example#2 (should NOT match because the second occurrence of `'My-Name'` does not contain both `Good` and `firstOnly`. However, the first occurence match. But I need every occurrence of `'My-Name'` to be checked against this criteria)

> {'Accept-Encoding, Accept', 'My-Name': 'PHPSESSID=aaa; Good;
>   firstOnly; path=/', 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=14400',
>   'My-Name': 'PHPSESSID=xxx; Good}

Example#3 (should match because every `'My-Name'` followed by `Good` and `firstOnly`):

> {'Accept-Encoding, Accept', 'My-Name': 'PHPSESSID=aaa; Good;
>   firstOnly; path=/', 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=14400',
>   'My-Name': 'PHPSESSID=xxx; Good; firstOnly}

My query is:

```
select mycol
from mytable
where mycol regexp "('|"")My-Name('|""):\\s*('|"")[^()<>@,;:\\""'/?={}]*\\s*=\\s*[^()<>@,;:""'?={}]*;\\s*((Good[^'""]*firstOnly)|(firstOnly[^'""]*Good))[^'""]*('|"")";
```

The above query returns the `Example#2` and `Example#3` records. It should NOT return Example#2.

Question: Can you point to me how to improve the query to check **every occurrence** of `'My-Name':` key against the criteria I have?

Comment: Do not use `nsregularexpression` tag unless you are using Swift/Objective-C.

Comment: Use `JSON` functions, not `REGEXPs` to poke around in such strings.